# pthread: does exit() explicitly close file descriptors of the thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

Assuming a thread opens some files etc. and thus obtains file descriptors. Is it guaranteed that `exit()` from a thread closes all file descriptors opened by the thread?

Comment: Doesn't `exit()` exit the entire process, not just a specific thread?

Comment: @Barmar, yes I know, but I was wondering if there's a possibility of FD leaks.

Comment: When a process exits, all its FDs are closed. Threads shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

exit() makes the current **process** exit, so all threads are destroyed (and it is not thread safe, so you should not use it in a multithreaded program).
File descriptors refers to processes not to threads, so when you call **pthread_exit()** or when you return from the entry function of a thread they won't be closed.